# citeyearpar in latex that would compress the years together

Tags: biblatex, citing

So I have two articles that have the same main author. I found an answer in this website to how to make the `\citeyearpar` to become `hyperref`ed:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}
    {}
    {\mkbibparens{\bibhyperref{\printdate}}}
    {, }
    {}
```

Now I apply it as `\citeyearpar{article1,article2)` what I get is (year1),(year2) but what I want is (year1,year2). Can I get help for this?

As an example I edit 01-introduction.tex from [bibtex tutorial](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex//doc/examples):

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !BIB TS-program = biber

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}
    {}
    {\mkbibparens{\bibhyperref{\printdate}}}
    {, }
    {}

%
% We use the database biblatex-examples.bib.
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
%
% Some generic settings.
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test \citeyearpar{companion,companion} Test Test Test.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Result is :
[image]

Comment: Please post a Minimum Working Example demonstrating the problem. That is, please make your code compile. That will help people to help you and increase your chances of getting useful suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third argument of `\DeclareCiteCommand` defines how each entry is going to be rendered. For the case at hand one has to specify different behaviour for the first element, the last element and any other element.  The various elements can be identified  by comparing the values of `citecount` and `citetotal`.  For the first element, i.e., the element whose `citecount=1` we include a leading open parenthesis using `\bibopenparens` and for the last element, the element such that `citecount=citetotal`, we add a trailing parenthesis with `\bibcloseparens`. Notice that `\bibopenparens` and `\bibcloseparens` ensure that the parenthesis are balanced.

The code to define the appropriate `\DeclareCiteCommand` is as follows:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}
    {}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{1}
      {\bibopenparen\bibhyperref{\printdate}}
      {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}
        {\bibhyperref{\printdate}\bibcloseparen}
        {\bibhyperref{\printdate}}%
      }%
    }
    {\addcomma\addspace}
    {}
```

producing the following output

[image]

Comment: Votes up for such a complete answer! Thank you very much.